# I can't read with AngularJS a Cookie created in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cookies

Hi I created a Cookie in PHP:

> setcookie( $name, $value, time() + $expire, '/', Host::$domain, isset
>   ( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] ) , true );

the domain is '127.0.0.1', beucase I haven't a website, I'm testing in XAMPP.
So, on index I show the $_COOKIE with var_dump, I see the cookie created, but I want to get Cookie data on AngularJS, so i do with this:

> alert ( $cookieStore.get('test') );

This gave undefined, but if I create a cookie from AngularJS

> $cookieStore.put('test','sugi pula');

The alert will show me the text.
The question is, how I can read a Cookie created from PHP ?

Answer (score 3):

The last argument to the php setcookie function is httponly.  This makes the cookie inaccessible to javascript.  If you set that to false you should be able to access the cookie.

Check your browser dev tools to see if the cookie is set to httponly.

Comment: Now i get error from Angular, SyntaxError: Unexpected token [first letter from cookie]

Comment: It looks like in this case you would want to use the $cookies object, not the $cookieStore.  $cookieStore tries to parse the value of the cookie as JSON.  So it should work if you do alert($cookies.test). [$cookies documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$cookies.get(<name of cookie>);` from `ngCookies` to get the values of the cookie, remember it should be stored in key value pair so ideally `$cookies.get(key);`

The official documentation is [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies).